# EJB Exeception : Channel Channel ID fc7b3f27 (outbound) of Remoting connection 31ad98ef to localhost/127.0.0.1:4447 can no longer process messages

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x

I am using a JBOSS 7 server which contains my deployed application. I created a java application to connect to the ejb that is deployed on the server . The connection goes perfectly and the server begins to process my request . After some processing it breaks out with the following exception :

```
Channel Channel ID fc7b3f27 (outbound) of Remoting connection 31ad98ef to localhost/127.0.0.1:4447 can no longer process messages
```

Does anyone  know what this means ?

Strangely I have a Virtual Machine and i replicated the exact same steps there and everything went fine . The java application executed successfully . I tried to search on the JBOSS community pages but couldnt find anything .

Is this some sort of limit that i am hitting ?

Comment: Hi @rockstar. I have exactly the same problem on wildfly 8.0.0.Final. The problem exists on one machine (the CI system) but not on another. It even seems to come and go on the problematic machine. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @MartinHöller . it was solved but since it was long time ago i dont quite remember . One thing i surely do remember is that some of these messages ( or similar messages ) were coming because the version of the jars was not compatible with the java platform . so once do a comparison of the two systems such that they are using exact jars/platforms . This is the only thing i remmber . It was the problem for me . Dont know if it will fix your issue . Good luck .

Comment: @rockstar , your solution is correct, will you please add that as an answer.  I just ran into this and it was related to a not compatible jar in my jboss modules.

Answer (score 0):

I had seen such exceptions in my application when java had crashed.
Check /var/log/messages if java had crashed... Java in my application had crashed because of "Out of memory" issues.

> 2018-09-10 00:16:16,278 ERROR [pool-2-thread-55] c.o.u.s.SessionCache
>   (SessionCache.java:236) - failed to invoke jndiName:
>   ejb:mega-app/acqServer//AcquisitionServerSessionBean!com.netapp.acquisition.aquisitionserverside.interfaces.remote.AcquisitionServerSession
>   java.io.IOException: Channel Channel ID b8337d0e (outbound) of
>   Remoting connection 30757f90 to localhost/127.0.0.1:80 has been closed
>   at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ChannelAssociation$1.handleClose(ChannelAssociation.java:123)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ChannelAssociation$1.handleClose(ChannelAssociation.java:115)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.remoting3.spi.SpiUtils.safeHandleClose(SpiUtils.java:54)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.remoting3.spi.AbstractHandleableCloseable$CloseHandlerTask.run(AbstractHandleableCloseable.java:501)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.remoting3.spi.AbstractHandleableCloseable.runCloseTask(AbstractHandleableCloseable.java:406)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.remoting3.spi.AbstractHandleableCloseable.closeComplete(AbstractHandleableCloseable.java:277)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel.closeAction(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:543)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.remoting3.spi.AbstractHandleableCloseable.closeAsync(AbstractHandleableCloseable.java:359)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionHandler.closeAllChannels(RemoteConnectionHandler.java:423)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionHandler.handleConnectionClose(RemoteConnectionHandler.java:114)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteReadListener$1$1.run(RemoteReadListener.java:56)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final] ... 3 more Wrapped by:
>   javax.ejb.EJBException: java.io.IOException: Channel Channel ID
>   b8337d0e (outbound) of Remoting connection 30757f90 to
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:80 has been closed at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:236)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144)
>   ~[jboss-client.jar:8.2.0.Final]   At the same time, java had crashed
>   as seen in /var/log/messages, Sep 10 00:16:15 dc2-scratch-ocum-01
>   kernel: [173427.465946] Out of memory: Kill process 7965 (java) score
>   239 or sacrifice child Sep 10 00:16:15 dc2-scratch-ocum-01 kernel:
>   [173427.465990] Killed process 7965 (java) total-vm:12704260kB,
>   anon-rss:3730368kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

Hope this helps...
Naresh